# 401 Unauthorized error when trying to browse a SharePoint site with host header on the server itself

Tags: 2007

I have an NTLM SharePoint site with host header on the Server. When I try to access this site from the server locally It asks me for the credentials 3 times and then finally giving me an unauthorized error. The site works fine from any non SharePoint farm machine with the same user credentials.

Now this may not be a big issue for me as I can browse the site from other machines. The real problem is regarding crawling as it is also getting access denied message in the crawl log and I think they both are related.

Server environment:
WINDOWS server 2003
MOSS 2007 with service pack2

Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to disable loopback checking.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: For clarification, it's not recommended to disable the loopback check altogether, but instead add your site to the BackConnectionHostNames "white list", which is described in Method 1 in the above article.